# Azure Devops: Search Commit History of Author on ALL Branches

Tags: .net, git, azure-devops, commit, git-history

How do I find the commit History for Author in All Branches in Azure Devops? This option, only lets me filter by author person on a Feature Branch. Want to Search All branches.

[image]

Comment: readers can vote up on Microsoft answer below, if they want this feature

Comment: we need something like this !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I find the commit History for Author in All Branches in Azure
>   Devops?

If you want to view the commit history within all branches in UI page, I'm afraid to say that until now, this feature does not be supported. As you can see,it only support filter in one specified branch with UI button.

In our official feature suggestion website, here has exists such feature suggested: [View history for whole GIT repository](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365478/view-history-for-whole-git-repository.html). And also, here has another feature suggestion which has been under review: [Show combined git branch history, including common ancestor](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/382989/show-combined-git-branch-history-including-common.html). I believe it will be released in the near future.

**Note**: You can vote and comment there. When has enough votes, the Product Group will consider it as plan.

Though it could not be achieved with UI, here has another work around you can try. You can use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#by-author) to filter the commit history by author within all branches.

Here is the sample:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.author={author name}&api-version=5.1
```

This API can list the commit records with the author filtered across All branches.

Comment: Yes this would be a great feature !

Comment: Not sure, the product group will regular review the suggestion which has enough votes. By the way, the more votes, the more urgent the demand for current features-) You can focus on this [Microsoft Roadmap project](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/recentlyupdated/)  which are showing the feature which in progress.

Comment: This feature is now [on the roadmap](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-do-i-view-the-history-of-all-branches-in-git/934801) (as a new feature request -- the two above were merged into presumably this one)

Answer (score 7):

The [Contributions Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions) plugin does this. You can filter by user by repository. It also includes activity on pull requests, work items.

[image: Screenshot of the Contributions Graph]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA shows the Git history from all the branches and from all the authors, we can also filter the commits. If you use any other IDE, check in the IDE.